# ASP.NET Identity and User.IsInRole

Tags: asp.net-core, claims-based-identity, asp.net-identity-2

I move project from Membership provider to ASP.NET Identity, I added the following role manager:

```
public class ApplicationRoleManager : RoleManager<ApplicationRole>
{
    public ApplicationRoleManager(RoleStore<ApplicationRole> store)
                : base(store)
    { }
    public static ApplicationRoleManager Create(IdentityFactoryOptions<ApplicationRoleManager> options,
                                            IOwinContext context)
    {
        return new ApplicationRoleManager(new
                RoleStore<ApplicationRole>(context.Get<ApplicationDbContext>()));
    }
}
```

and I try to add user to role:

```
        await UserManager.AddClaimAsync("46bf12b9-6b9e-43f9-ad9b-8fff27987978", claim: new Claim(ClaimTypes.Role.ToString(), "Admin"));
```

record is added, but User.IsInRole does not work. Why and how to fix?

Answer (score 0):

Claims and roles are different, see [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authorization/roles) and [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authorization/claims). You should be using the method `AddToRoleAsync` which is contained in the `UserManager<T>`. Here's an example.

```
var user = new ApplicationUser
{
    Username = "Rob@Microsoft.com",
    Email = "Rob@Microsoft.com"
};

var result = await _userManager.CreateAsync(user, "P@ssw0rd");
if (result.Succeeded)
{
    await _userManager.AddToRoleAsync(user, "Admin");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Best to use `AddToRoleAsync` method - it does very similar thing and you don't have to do it yourself. Plus if internal implementation changes, you won't have to update your code.

As for `User.IsInRole` does not work - I suspect it does not work immediately after your call. But if you log user out and log them back in again, you'll see the role in place. This is because `User.IsInRole` checks the cookie, where as `AddClaimAsync` adds the claim to the database. And cookie is not refreshed from the DB on every call, hence you don't see the newly added information in DB when looking on a cookie. There are ways to force this, but this is beyond this question.